# Generate xml files during sbt build

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to generate xml files during sbt build based on higher level config(lets say yaml), then package them into the tar file(by sbt-native-packager). What would be the simplest way to achieve that?

One way I can think of is to add twirl to project/build.sbt and than use it to write custom task. Is there some simpler way to do that?

Comment: Scala used to be shipped with tools for XML, but since 2.11 it is not anymore, xml lib has been separated out. So probably you will have to include something anyway, just up to your taste what that would be https://github.com/scala/scala-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use twirl, you would need to add twirl as a plugin to the your projects builds build - it's a bit meta, the location of your twirl files will be a bit unintuitive (`projcet/src/main/twirl`). I've done it, but in my opinion it's just not worth it for most use cases.

I would instead just use `scala-xml`. If using sbt 0.13 (ie, Scala 2.10), then you can just embed the xml directly in your Scala code, otherwise for sbt 1.0 you may need to add a dependency on `scala-xml` in your `project/plugins.sbt` (though possibly sbt 1.0 already depends on `scala-xml`, not sure).

Here's an example of a task that generates XML:

https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/4a75ab0773b2cc3f55b6c5fae3f96ba08ddcf4c0/project/SbtMavenPlugin.scala#L47

Scroll down to see examples of embedding xml in Scala:

https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/4a75ab0773b2cc3f55b6c5fae3f96ba08ddcf4c0/project/SbtMavenPlugin.scala#L158-L162